# Making this JS code unobtrusive. Writing an event listener for unknown id

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I've been building out the functionality for this UI. These are a pair of tabs I want to write a listener for, to make my js unobtrusive. It was blocking me from going forward. Now that I'm refactoring, it's time to fix it. I want to write an event listener that gets the id of the tab that was clicked, and assigns it to a variable. This is what I have:

```
<ul id="gal">

   <li class="glyphicons camera active" onclick="pullActive(this.id);" id="viewAll"><a href="#" ><i></i> View all photos <strong>(43)    </strong></a>
   </li>
   <li class="glyphicons circle_plus tab-stacked" onclick="pullActive(this.id);" id="addPhotos"><a href="#"><i></i> <span>Add Photos</span></a>
   </li>
</ul>

function pullActive(id){

 // gets the class for that id
  var getClassy = document.getElementById(id).className;
  findClass(getClassy, id);
  loadNew();

}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. This was a really dumb question, but my brain is wracked, today.

Comment: no prob, glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without jQuery you would have to do

```
var item = document.querySelector("#gal");
item.attachEventHandler("click", function(ev) {
   if (ev.target.tagName === "LI") {
      var id = ev.target.id;
      // ...
   }
});
```

In jquery (as you tagged your question like this) it would look like this

```
$(function() {
   $("#gal").delegate("li", "click", function() {
      var id = this.id;
      // ...
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

## jQuery solution:

```
$('#gal li').on('click', function () {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    var id = this).id;
    console.log(className, id);
});
```

## Vanilla solution:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#gal li'), function (glyphicon) {
    glyphicon.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var className = glyphicon.className;
        var id = glyphicon.id
        console.log(className, id);
    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NZ3y/1/) containing both examples.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, this would be

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( '#gal' ).on( 'click', 'li', function() {
    var id = this.id
  });
});
```

The benefit of this approach is that you only have one event handler (defined on the ul) vs. having one for each li. Hope this helps.